# Domain of $f$ and $f^{-1}$, where $f(x) = \ln(2+\ln x)$

Tags: calculus

Find (a) the domain of $f$ and (b) $f^{-1}$ and its domain for the function

$$f(x) = \ln(2+\ln x).$$

This is a polynomial; thus, it will be true no matter what. So I do not have to set this polynomial equal to zero. These are the steps I performed.

1) $e^{\ln(2 +\ln x)}$

2) $e^2+x=0$

I believe I am on the wrong track. Any insight how I should approach this problem?

Comment: This is not a polynomial

Comment: Since when did $e^{a+b} = e^a+e^b$???

Answer (score 1):

First of all $f(x)=\ln(2+\ln x)$ is definitely not a polynomial.

You are asked to find the domain of $f$. Which is the possible values of $x\in \Bbb{R}$ in which your function can be evaluated.

Now we know that the natural logarithm is well defined in $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ so this implies that both

1) $x>0$ and

2) $2+ln(x)>0$

For number 2) we have that $\ln(x)>-2 \Rightarrow x>\frac{1}{e^2}>0$

Since restriction number 2) implies number 1), we just consider 2) and we have that the possible values $x$ can take, that is the domain of $f(x)$ is $D=(\frac{1}{e^2},+\infty)$.

Now in the second case, you have to find $f^{-1}$ you can do this by setting $y=\ln(2+\ln(x))$ and try to make $x$ the subject of the formula. Once you've managed to do this, and obtained $f^{-1}$ proceed in the same way to calculate its domain. Remember to first of all check the possible restrictions on $x$

Answer (score 0):

given $f(x)=\ln(2+\ln(x))$ and it must be $$2+\ln(x)>0$$ and this means $$x>e^{-2}$$
to find the inverse function we can calculate
$$y=\ln(2+\ln(x))$$ for $x$:
$$e^{y}=2+\ln(x)$$
$$e^{y}-2=\ln(x)$$
$$e^{e^{y}-2}=x$$

Comment: The answer is incomplete. Where is the domain of $f^{-1}$?